# Differences between commands of Cassandra CLI and Cassandra CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-cli, wso2-cep

I am trying to run the following wso2cep sample.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Sample+0067+-+Publishing+Map+Events+via+Cassandra+Transport

But in the latest cassandra releases we cannot find the cassandra-cli. So we have to use cassandra CQL instead.

How to run the following commands which targeted cassandra-cli, within  CQL?

```
 Create a keyspace: create keyspace CEP_KS;

 Use keyspace: use CEP_KS admin 'admin';

 Create column family: create column family CF_Transactions with comparator = 'UTF8Type' and caching='ALL';
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cassandra-cli** is an old client using **Thrift** protocol and now deprecated, you should use **cqlsh** client which is using the new CQL binary protocol

Comment: Yeah I used it. But above commands cannot be run in cqlsh as they are. Are there syntax differences or something?

Comment: You need to create a schema (CREATE TABLE ...) when using **cqlsh**